# how can I multi select items in listbox with wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I'm trying to code a listbox which you can select multiple items.

```
ContactResultsData.SelectedItem = ContactResultsData.Items[0];
```

This code is useful for selecting one item. But I want to multiselect. how can I do? thanks.

note: my selection mode of listbox already is multiselect .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use collection `SelectedItems` to add items, remove items or do smth else with selection

```
ContactResultsData.SelectedItems.Add(ContactResultsData.Items[0]);
ContactResultsData.SelectedItems.Add(ContactResultsData.Items[1]);
```